# When do past participles of reflexive verbs agree with subject?

Tags: accord, verbes-pronominaux

On a random online quiz, I was presented with the following one:

> Elles se sont ____ dans leur malheur.

The two options were *complu* and *complues* (past participle of *complaire*). I picked *complues* and was told that *complu* was correct.

I am very confused because agreement of past participle with the auxiliary verb *être* is very obvious to me.

I have already read [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/21608/18420) and I think *se* (elles) is the direct object (there's nothing else that could serve as the object). Am I wrong here or elsewhere?

Comment: https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-des-verbes-pronominaux-188.php

Comment: @Sharcoux No. According to the link provided by LPH, *se complaire* is a verb that never agrees with subject/object, and such *complu* is always correct (no *complue/complus/complues* in this case).

Comment: OMG, my bad. I didn't pay enough attention!